# geom_histogram() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building the histogram in R using ggplot2 package using the below code-

```
ggplot(cohort, aes(x=ltv))+
 geom_histogram()
```

It is supposed to result in the histogram returning 30 bins as the default, but it is not doing it. It returns one bar instead of 30 why would that be?

Comment: When I do `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram()`, it has 30 bins. Please provide sample data by editing your question and [pasting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) in the output from `dput(head(cohort$ltv,n=50))` (50 or so, enough to demonstrate). (Refs on reproducible questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.)

Comment: Are you sure you've got a numeric vector, not a factor or something else?

Comment: You could also just have a single unique value. But who knows, we are just stabbing in the dark without any data provided, and no response.